# Polymorphism and std::vector

Tags: c++

So I have a vector of "Widgets"

```
std::vector<Widget> widgets;
```

And a class called dial which extends Widget

```
class Dial : public Widget
```

And also a loop which loops through all the Widgets in `widgets`. However, there is and update method in Widget which gets overriden in Dial, and whenever I loop through `widgets` it calls Widget's update and not Dial's update. How can I fix this? (It also calls Widget's `draw` and not Dial's as well)

Comment: This has nothing to do with vectors.

Comment: @chris How so? I AM using vectors

Comment: You are the victim of *slicing*. To fix it you must use a vector of `Widget*` and not `Widget`.

Comment: @jogojapan I am trying that but it says std has no member unique_ptr

Comment: @MarkRansom Alright, what can i do to fix it

Comment: @KhanPower You need C++11 for `unique_ptr`. Depending on the compiler you are using, the `-std=c++11` command line option might get you there.